# Looking for a program that generated Property List with specific output

Tags: cocos2d-x, texturepacker, property-list

I've been using TexturePacker to create spritesheet and property list for game, TexturePacker's property list:

```
        <key>Sprite_1.png</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aliases</key>
            <array/>
            <key>spriteOffset</key>
            <string>{0,0}</string>
            <key>spriteSize</key>
            <string>{27,35}</string>
            <key>spriteSourceSize</key>
            <string>{27,35}</string>
            <key>textureRect</key>
            <string>{{99,17},{27,35}}</string>
            <key>textureRotated</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
```

Recently i know some property list with output like this:

```
        <key>Sprite_1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>height</key>
            <integer>33</integer>
            <key>offsetX</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>offsetY</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>originalHeight</key>
            <integer>33</integer>
            <key>originalWidth</key>
            <integer>22</integer>
            <key>width</key>
            <integer>22</integer>
            <key>x</key>
            <integer>24</integer>
            <key>y</key>
            <integer>34</integer>
        </dict>
```

EDIT: add [link](https://pastebin.com/jUjkT2jk) to full plist file.

Anyone know which program that generate property list like the second one? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share that PLIST file?

Comment: Here, i added it to the post.

Comment: Thanks for full plist file. There is no such hint about this data format is. However, texture packer can generate above format by following customization steps on https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/documentation#customization

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't know texture packer can do that.